# How can I add Garuda look & feel on Arch Linux?

Tags: desktop-environment, garuda-linux

I just installed Arch Linux (https://archlinux.org/) on my system with a number of desktop environments including (Gnome, Plasma, Enlightment, etc).  I'd like to add the Garuda look & feel for KDE (https://garudalinux.org/downloads.html) to my system.   Unfortunately, it appears Garuda is an entire distro.

I would appreciate help on how I can include Garuda look & feel to my Arch Linux.

Comment: Are you referring to their "Dr460nized" look? Maybe [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/n03jby/how_to_get_garuda_gui_on_arch_linux/) would help? Just pointing out - Garuda is an Arch -based distro, so the easiest way might be just installing Garuda.

Comment: Download the Garuda iso, live boot into it. Copy all KDE themes, icons etc. and save in your local disk.

Answer (score 0):

Install the correct themes. The system theme is sweet-dark. The icons are beautyline or sweet